# Apache2.4.25 using system default openssl instead of new version provided during compilation

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, mod-ssl

Trying to compile apache2.4.25 from source on Fedora 15 with dynamically linked mod_ssl. Fedora15 server has a default openssl version (`OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012`) and newer openssl library (`OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`) is installed in `/usr/local/ssl/bin`.

## Compilation steps

```
./configure --enable-ssl=shared --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/lib --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/lib/pcre-config

make 
make install
```

After installation, shared library is still pointing to older openssl version

```
ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fb715087000)

ls -lrt  /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jun  2 14:43 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.0j
```

`libssl.s0.10` has a sym link to system default openssl version. 
Tried compiling without specific custom path to openssl library and still the same results with `libssl.so` still pointing to system openssl version.

Even tried setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to point to new openssl lib path, yet no luck.

Comment: if your dir with the new libs is /mynewlibs and it contains four libs: libssl.so -> libssl.so.10, libssl.so.10, libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.10, libcrypto.so.10,then after invoking in the same shell export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mynewlibs/ you will have your ldd output pointed top the right libs

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by deleting the old OpenSSL library(`_libssl.so.10_`) and recompiling with the latest OpenSSL library.

Once this was installed, copied the older `_libssl.so_` file back to the directory it was initially in. This has solved the issue for now, but not recommended on a production server :)